# Consolidate duplicate entries into one row

Tags: crystal-reports

My report looks like:

```
Number   Route    Transportnumber
1         A            1A
2         B            2B
3         C            3C
3         C            3CE
```

How can I get the information from number 3 into a single row? It should look like:

```
Number   Route    Transportnumber
1         A            1A
2         B            2B
3         C            3C, 3CE
```

I tried the following formula in a stored procedure:

```
whileprintingrecords;
stringvar s;
if s="" then
     s:={sp.Transportnumber}
else
     s:=s+", "+{sp.Transportnumber};
```

This instead results in:

```
Number   Route    Transportnumber   Formula
1         A            1A              1A
2         B            2B              2B
3         C            3C              3C
3         C            3CE             3C, 3CE
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your report, create a *Group* based on `Route`. Then hide the Group Header and Details section. Instead, put *all* the fields you want to see in the Group Footer. This step ensures that even if Routes repeat, you only ever see one of each letter.

---

Then create a formula with a shared variable, called `RouteTransports`. Place it in your Details section. Whenever the group changes, reset it with `RouteTransports = ""`. Whenever the group doesn't change, add the value of `Transportnumber` to your variable. Something like:

```
RouteTransports = RouteTransports & ", " & {yourtable.Transportnumber}
```

---

Finally, create a final formula `ShowRouteTransports` in the Group Footer to display the results with `RIGHT(RouteTransports, LEN(RouteTransports)-2)` The end result will look like this:

```
Number   Route    Transport Number
1        A        1A
2        B        2B
3        C        3C, 3CE
```